# Getting selected values from dropdown options inside nested ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to access value of selected value of dropdown options. But problem is that i already have ng-repeat as parent div and inside that options in dropdowns are also using ng-repeat. So basically its nested ng-repeat.

So I'm not able to access selected values.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srjahir32/44a0thqt/)

```
<div ng-controller="csrClrt">
<div  ng:repeat="item in items track by $index">

  <md-list one class="md-accordion">
            <md-input-container>
                   <label>Face Style:</label>
                  <md-select ng-model="style">
                   <md-option ng-value="user.name" ng:repeat="user in styles">{{user.name}}</md-option>
                  </md-select>
          </md-input-container>  
   </md-list>
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" value="get selected value" ng-click="getvalue()"/>
</div>

                    <p>
                    if i ttry out of parent ng repeat
                    </p>
                     <md-input-container>
                   <label>Face Style:</label>
                  <md-select ng-model="style">
                   <md-option ng-value="user.name" ng:repeat="user in styles">{{user.name}}</md-option>
                  </md-select>
          </md-input-container>
                              <div>

<input type="button" value="get selected value" ng-click="getvalue()"/>
                              </div>

                                 </div>
```

AngularJS

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('csrClrt', function ($scope) {
     $scope.items=["0"];
     stylesdata=[{name:"a"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"}];
     var style=[];
     for(var i=0;i<stylesdata.length;i++)
     {
       style.push({
        name:stylesdata[i].name
       })
     }
     $scope.styles=style;
     $scope.getvalue=function()
     {

       alert($scope.style);
     }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat isolates the scope if you want to do it without an isolated scope then bind the variables as an object and not an independent variable like this

```
<md-select ng-model="a.style">
```

and access it as

```
 alert($scope.a.style);
```

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/44a0thqt/1/

Comment: But the both dropdown is showing the same name, because the model name is same. It' should be provided with different name.

Comment: yes if we need different select value for each elements then need a diff name but if same then was my ans in terms of why same name in repeat and outside behaves differently

Comment: Yup. but it's bad idea to use two different controls with same model name.

Comment: @RameshRajendran thats true but I have no idea whether the OP que was in terms of implementation or idea of understanding :).

Comment: Just go with two alert box to show the value. You can see it from my fiddler. Any way OP is soo silent here. I'll go to lunch . bye! bye!.

Comment: Thanks @VinodLouis It really helped me. I needed it for implementation. Actually parent ng-repeat is for accordians. Inside accordians i've multiple dropdowns. And Needed to access values from these dropdowns. Will it work that way ?

Comment: @user3288891 did you reed my answer?

Comment: yes if you want to keep same context then used same scope binding same variable if each loop needs an different value of drop-down then use  diff scope  binding difff variables

Answer (score 1):

You had same model name for the both dropdowns `ng-model="style">`. that is a problem

---

> **You should provide spate name to the `ng-model` directive**

### Update

Also your first `select` tag inside of the `ng-repeat` So it will be create  multiple `select` tag's. This time you should pass the index and get the data.

So kindly change your first drodown model name to `ng-model="item.style">`. So now you can get the value by using the index count as like `$scope.items[indexNumber].style`

See the demo : https://jsfiddle.net/44a0thqt/3/